# Как изменить обработчик нажатия для Textfield?

Tags: kotlin, onclicklistener

Возможно ли изменить метод `setonclicklistener` для объекта `textField` и если да, то как?
По задумке нужно реализовать ввод даты и времени через `textField`, чтобы при нажатии вызывался объект `Calendar` и `TimePicker`.
Хотелось бы увидеть пример реализации, если таковой имеется.

Comment: Разве для этого необходимо менять метод `setOnClickListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я когда-то реализовал выбор даты рождения подобным способом

```
txtBirthDate.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        popupPicker()
        txtBirthDate.setOnClickListener { 
            popupPicker() 
        }
    } else {
        txtBirthDate.setOnClickListener(null)
    }
}
```

Где `popupPicker()` -- метод где вы показываете что вам надо для выбора даты или времени.